# Error when trying to install Lazypredict, problem with lightgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm, automl, pycaret

I'm trying to install Lazypredict, an autoML python library, on macOS 10.14.6.

Thus, I simply run
"pip install lazypredict" in the terminal , it wants to install lightgbm, but always fails to do so. I think it tries to install lightgbm through pip although I have already installed it with brew (as recommendend).

Hence i get such errors and really don't know what to do. I already have CMake installed too
Do you have ideas of what could enable me to install lazypredict ?
PS: Same happenned with other auto ML packages such as PyCaret

---

The errors I get are the following:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for lightgbm
Running setup.py clean for lightgbm
Failed to build lightgbm
Installing collected packages: lightgbm
Running setup.py install for lightgbm ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Exception: Please install CMake and all required dependencies first

Comment: Have the same problem with Lazy predict, might mean that they need to update the package to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION 1 (Recommended)

`LazyPredict` works with specific versions of other `libraries`, I recommend you to work with [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) or [Kaggle Notebook](https://kaggle.com/). They create a separate environment having multiple versions of other libraries, when you install `lazypredict` on colad or kaggle you won't face any issues.

One more reason to use `lazypredict` on Colab or Kaggle is that this library is just for testing purposes you cannot use this library for deployment, and it won't work on large datasets.

---

#### SOLUTION 2

As I mentioned `lazypredict` depends on specific versions of other libraries, you can search on google and will find a list of those libraries along with their version, try to manually install those versions **but it is a time-consuming step**, the other way is to install a new `python` version within which you can create a `Virtual Environment` and then try to install `lazypredict` in it.

---

#### SOLUTION 3 (only perform if you know docker)

If you are aware of [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) you can install a python image in it, a fresh install that does not contain any libraries, so you can install `lazypredict` in it.

Comment: I will try that. Is it the same with PyCaret ?

Comment: Try installing `PyCaret` in a separate `Virtual Environment`